# How to use java project in different java project?

Tags: java

I created java project 1 woth class Hello.java

```
package com.test.java1;


@WebServlet("/hello")
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ....doLogic
    }


    }
```

pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>java1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I build it and copy the war file to my java to lib folder 
now I created java2 and I want to use it

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>java1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/java1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</systemPath>
    <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

and tried to call it from my second java and I call Compilation error

```
package com.test2.java2

import com.test.java1
public class Test {
    Hello hel - new Hell();
}
```

Comment: How did you "build it"? You need to `mvn install`.

Comment: build = mvn install and then I got war

Comment: I'm pretty sure Maven doesn't allow `war` files as dependencies

Comment: A war file contains a full web application, this is not something you would import into another Java project. Let your project 1 just build a jar.

Comment: What is your plan? How do you intend to run it/deploy it? You should keep it simple and have one war you will deploy and other modules should be added as jar libraries. There are some workarounds like maven-war-overlay, but to me it looks like you've chosen a wrong start. Are you just testing things or is it some simplified real world problem?

Comment: i WANT TO USE CLASS FROM JAVA1

Comment: Why are you using caps lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might just be a copy and paste error but you have miss spelt Hello when you try to call it so change:
    public class Test {
    Hello hel - new Hell();}
to:

```
public class Test {
Hello hel - new Hello();}
```

Also your making your doGet method protected and presumably calling it from your main method - you cant do this as protected methods can only be called from the same package so if you move your main class to:

```
package com.test.java1
```

you will be able to call the method.

Also your Hello class is a webservlet? Im not sure that you can make the doGet a protected method as it is by definition accepting public calls to it with a HttpRequest and httpResponse. SO changing that to public can potentially fix other issues - not sure why you would want to make it protected.

Answer (score 1):

It's even better to use the Maven on board mechanism. Often repository manager are used for that kind of use-case, but you can "simulate" it locally, too.

1. build the project that artifact you want re-use `mvn package`
2. install that artifact locally `mvn install`
3. refer the artifact in the same way you declare external dependencies in your pom

In your IDE you should see, that the dependencies are well resolved

In a more professional scenario, especially if more than one person is in the development involved, you should use a repository manager like Nexus.